# PHP - Array does not turn into two-dimensional array

Tags: php, sql

I need to make my array better.
I am getting data from database and i have milestones and milestone_parts. i want two-dimensional array. I need data of milestones in the **first** dimension and milestone_parts in the **second** dimension.

With this code:

```
$query = " 
         SELECT 
         a.id AS `milestone_id`, 
         a.titel AS `milestone_titel`, 
         a.client AS `client`,
         a.verkocht_id AS `milestone_verkocht_id`,

         b.id AS `milestonefase_id`, 
         b.titel AS `milestonefase_titel`,
         b.milestone_id AS `milestonefase_milestone_id`,
         b.omschrijving AS `milestonefase_omschrijving`
         FROM `milestones` a
         INNER JOIN `milestone_parts` b ON a.id=b.milestone_id
         WHERE a.verkocht_id = '99' 
         ";

         $result= $db->query($dbh, $query);


            while ($row = $db->fetchassoc($result))
            {
                $stone = array($row['milestone_verkocht_id'], $row['milestone_id'], $row['milestone_titel'], $row['client']);
                $fase = array($row['milestonefase_milestone_id'],$row['milestonefase_id'],$row['milestonefase_titel']);
                $stone[] = $fase;
                echo '<pre>'; print_r($stone); echo '</pre>';
            }
```

I get this as result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 99
    [1] => 6
    [2] => string
    [3] => string
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 10
            [2] => string
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => 99
    [1] => 6
    [2] => string
    [3] => string
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 11
            [2] => string
        )

)
```

but I need (with names) this:

```
Array
(
    [milestone_verkocht_id] => 99 // This is project id
    [milestone_id] =>  6
    [milestone_title] => string
    [client] => string
    [10] => Array
        (
            [milestonefase_milestone_id] => 6
            [milestonefase_id] =>  10
            [milestone_title] => string
        )
    [11] => Array
        (
            [milestonefase_milestone_id] =>  6
            [milestonefase_id] => 11
            [milestone_title] => string
        )
    [12] => Array
        (
            [milestonefase_milestone_id] => 6
            [milestonefase_id] => 12
            [milestone_title] => string
        )

)
```

Can you help me or do you have a solution? Help me please!

Comment: Get id of a project, group items of current array, according to this id.

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can cycle each field returned by the query, checking the field name and making new arrays

```
$stones = array();
while ($row = $db->fetchassoc($result)) {
    $fase = array();
    $stone = array('milestones' => array());
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        if (strpos($k, 'milestonefase_') === 0) {
            $fase[$k] = $v;
        } else {
            $stone[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    if(!isset($stones[$stone['milestone_id']])) {
      $stones[$stone['milestone_id']] = $stone;
    }
    $stones[$stone['milestone_id']]['milestones'][$fase['milestonefase_id']] = $fase;
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($stones, true).'</pre>';
```

**Edit**
made some changes in order to match the request. Now we use $stones to store the information we already have on a milestone, adding to it the different "$fase" returned from the query
Probably a more clean way is to retrieve all the information with two different queries one for milestones and the other for the fases

**Edit2**
Added a sub-array for the milestone fases

Comment: Sir, This does not work:

`$fase = [];`
`$stone = [];`

Comment: if you are running an old php version, you just need to replace the "[]" with "array()"

Comment: I chnaged `$fase = [];` into `$fase = array();` but it did not change the result.

Comment: If there are 4 milestonefases, which is connected to 1 milestone, it need to be show 1 milestone and 4 milestonefases and not 1milestone 1 milestonefase 4 times

example:
milestone 
milestonefase
milestonefase
milestonefase
milestonefase

NOT 
milestone 
milestonefase
milestone 
milestonefase
milestone 
milestonefase

Comment: well, then we have another problem: inner join connects only 1 row per table, so you will have the same "$stone" repeated more then once with different "$fase"s inside... I've edited the code to match your need ;)

Comment: Yes! thanks sir. My problem is solved with your code. Thanks!

Comment: glad to be helpful :)

Comment: Sir, because you solved this problem (thanks again), I got another problem to set my array into table-rows. To make table-rows, the milestonefase 10, 11, 12 need to go away and my array need to like this: 
`Array
(
    [milestone_verkocht_id] => 99
    [milestone_id] =>  6
    [milestone_title] => example title
    [client] => stackov
    [milestones] => Array
   (
        [10] => Array  // this is milestonefase 10
        (
            ............
            .............
        )
        [11] => Array 
        (
         .............
         .............
        )
)`

Comment: You can add a sub-array (named "milestones") to $stone, adding fases to it. I've edited the code this way ;)

Comment: This worked but how can i **count** all milestonefases of a milestone to get milestonefases into a table row
I tried this but it did not work

`for ($i = 0; $i < count($milestone['milestonesfases']); $i++)
{
     echo '<tr>';    
     echo '<td>'. $milestone[$i]['milestonefase_titel'] . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
}`

Comment: you can use foreach($milestone['milestones'] as $fase) {echo '<tr><td>'. $fase['milestonefase_titel'] . '</td></tr>'; }